# Ubuntu 16.04 - Portuguese on system76 (US) layout

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout, input-language, internationalization

I have a system76 computer with a standard [system76 layout](https://d1vhcvzji58n1j.cloudfront.net/images/laptops/oryx/orxp1/kb-top_600-dfede2c045.jpg).

I use Portuguese accents all the time, so I need quick access to them. Typically, I use US international keyboard with dead keys. Hence, to make for instance `á`, I type `'`+`a`. I had this working on my Ubuntu 14.04, however after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04, it stopped working on all applications, except bash for some reason.

I have the following outputs

```
    > gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources
    [('xkb', 'us+intl')]
    > gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current
    uint32 0
```

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you have XIM enabled as input method, and run into [bug #1573755](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1573755). If so, try to open *Language Support*, change to "IBus" as input method, and relogin.

*Edit:*

Since the above idea didn't work, you may want to check which is your currently selected keyboard layout by running these commands:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it's IBus already

Comment: @madness: Hmm.. Then can you try with "none"?

Comment: Doesn't work either :(

Comment: @madness: I just edited my (attempt at an) answer. Can you please run those two commands in a terminal window, and let us know what they output.

Comment: I've updated my question with this info

Comment: @madness: So you only have us+intl. Then I have an idea, which doesn't make so much sense, but still has proved to help in some cases: Add the basic English (US) layout too, so you have two layouts to switch between. Then switch back and forth a couple of times.

Comment: I don't really see how this would help, because with basis English (US) I have the same problem. Anyway, thanks for all the help! It really seems to be a bug in this version.

Comment: @madness: The thing would be that the switching in itself might fix some glitch. Last idea: What if you open a guest session? Are the dead keys broken there too?

Comment: Yes, doesn't work either :(

Comment: @madness: Then I'm unfortunately out of ideas for now. Hopefully someone else can help.